# Why do wired and wireless mice have different accelerations?

Tags: mouse

For some reason, when I plug in a wired mouse to my iMac, and then plug in a wireless mouse, the acceleration of both are totally different.

The acceleration curve for the wired mouse seems to be about the same as it would be on a Windows computer, while a wireless mouse has the typical annoying Mac acceleration curve that many are aware of, which is an increased acceleration—when moving the mouse slowly, the acceleration is low, and when moving it quickly, the acceleration is high.

I noticed this years ago but only recently switched back from a wired to a wireless mouse after it finally died, and I decided to take the jump back to wireless mice since they are far more common than wired ones these days.

Is this just me or do other people have this happening to them as well?

Comment: Are these mice the same brands or models?

Comment: The only wired one I have is [this one](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000H51GA6/), although mine is branded by HP. I recall testing this with the most recent Apple wired mouse, too, before they went wireless. The wireless ones are all Logitech, including the Logitech v470, with the exception of the Apple Magic Mouse which I also have.